# gitlab flow with release branches

Tags: git, devops, branching-and-merging, cicd, branching-strategy

with gitlab flow with release branching strategy, this is what my understanding is,

1. you have one main branch which is long lived protected branch
2. developers branch out feature branches from main and merges back in to main
3. on every pull request merge - CI/CD pipeline runs unit tests and deploys code on `development branches`
4. once tested, you create pull request `main --> UAT` for deploying code on `UAT`  environment and finally
5. you create pull request `UAT-->Prod` to deploy on `prod` envionment

**Problem/Issue**

what if we have planned to features for the release. however during UAT we realize that one feature has lots of issues and we can't move it production, but other feature is ready to go.

how do I cherry pick features to deploy to production, considering feature_1 (not ready to deploy) is committed before feature_2 which is ready to deploy?

Comment: you can use feature flags

Comment: @Ôrel I am using bitbucket cloud.